# is it normal to work as an university professor in engineering but have no real professional experience (in the industry)?

Tags: teaching, university, industry, answering-questions

I work as a university assistant professor, I teach engineering-related subjects.
However, I have no *real professional experience in engineering* (**in the industry**), I've never worked as an engineer or something, and in my country, you can't work in 2 positions *obviously* (you can't have 2 salaries) even if you are teaching at university, the only option is to start your own firm! and I don't think it's a good idea to start my own firm (my own business) without professional experience in the field.

BUT, sometimes students ask questions about the *real world*, about real problems and I find it sometimes "*awkward*" not to answer their questions because I don't have professional experience (in the industry).

- so is it normal to work at university without experience in the industry? does not this make me look *less* compared to the rest of my colleagues?
- if so, what are my best *options* to get some professional experience in the field?
- finally, how should I answer students' questions if I stayed without experience in the industry?

Comment: Which question are you asking? The title question and the last paragraph are two completely different questions.

Comment: hmmm, you are right, I will edit it.

Comment: "you can't have 2 salaries": Why? I know a lot of (rich) people who has even more than two salaries.

Comment: @onurcanbektas: The OP states this is not possible in her country. Is the country of the OP and the people you know the same?

Comment: Are you less compares to your collegues? If so, how did they get the experience from?

Comment: Could you maybe invite once a real world expert to your class (either a professional or one of your collegues) and tell your students they should direct all questions to the expert?

Comment: @user111388 can't be done each time a student has a question !

Comment: @David: I mean you say "please write down your questions, the expert will come the lesson after Christmas" or similar

Comment: Allure asked you to clarify which question you were asking, and instead you added more questions.  One question per post, please.

Comment: For the most part the answers are "it depends..." so these are not suitable questions for this site.

Comment: As pointed out in another comment, the following: (quote) "you can't work in 2 positions obviously (you can't have 2 salaries)" is (as an absolute) wrong. However your specific contract (or laws on working hours) may prevent you from having more than 1 job and thus more than 1 salary. - As to your question: A lot of academics don't have industry experience at all. Some people went to work in industry and came back to teach. - Especially academia can be accommodating with part time positions to allow staff to hold another position - e.g. in industry (also for the connection). Some do consulting

Comment: It is even desirable to not have industrial experience

Comment: @SSimon why is that?

Comment: @David because as young tenure track stuff you are expected to do research in R1 and R2, consulting and industry is usually reserved for seniors

Answer (score -5):

> What are my best options to get some professional experience in the field?

You could get a secondment to a company to do specific (applied) research for example.

When I was a student, some of the best professors had spent time in both industry and academia. One I remember had used temperature sensors to record brake disk temperatures on a testing rig - they were glowing... So he was slightly amused at how we were finding it difficult to calibrate a temperature sensor for use between ambient and 100 deg C... He got us sorted though.

Comment: So many "experts", sorry downvoters, who know about my professors...

Comment: Perhaps it is downvoted for suggesting an academic professor should do some "real" work :)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I suspect the downvotes are because you didn't really address OP's specific question...perhaps this should be a comment?

Comment: @cag51 it was offering a suggestion for "what are my best options to get some professional experience" as per the op's post. So I offered a suggestion to what the OP wrote - did the downvoters read though?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I proposed an edit that will hopefully make the relevance clearer (feel free to revert if you disagree) -- perhaps that will help.

Comment: @cag51 the edit is fine with me - you kept the spirit of the post, thanks.

Comment: @SolarMike Perhaps the downvotes are for telling personal anecdotes rather than answering the question?

Comment: @user151413 they come from experience...

Comment: This is a question-and-answer site, not a question-and-I-tell-some-anecdotes-from-my-experience site.  These should be comments or go to chat.

Comment: @user151413 most of the answers on this stack are about academia and experience, such as how to cope in a given situation, teaching etc

Comment: ... though the substance of the answer should be on facts and recommendations, not on anecdotes.  Omitting the anecdote, this is a one-line answer, which are rarely the best (but common with some users).

Comment: @user151413 it was a fact.